# Getting the Device File for a USB Device with IOKit

Tags: macos, cocoa, serial-port, usb

Following the tutorials on the Apple Developer website, I managed to figure out how to enumerate either serial ports or connected USB devices, with the former giving me the information I need about which device file to read and write from and the latter giving me the device's name. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to go about figuring out which device file corresponds to which USB device.

Ideally, I would create an USB device iterator, create an interface for each one to get the information I need, and then do something to get the path to the device file corresponding to the USB device. I have everything implemented, except for this mysterious something.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are the USB devices in question USB to serial adapters?